# Connect BigQuery as a source to Data Fusion in another GCP project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am trying to connect BigQuery of ProjectA to Data Fusion of ProjectB and its asking me to enter a service key file. I have tried to upload the service key file to Cloud Storage of ProjectB and provided the link but it's asking me to provide a local file path.

Can someone help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this, grant BQ permission of project A to data fusion in project B.

1. service-**project_number**@gcp-sa-datafusion.iam.gserviceaccount.com.
2. **project_number**-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com.

Steps:

1. Navigate to the customer project that contains the CDF instance and copy the project number (this is found on the Home Page in the Project Info card)
2. Navigate to the project that contains the resources you would like to interact with.
3. In the sidebar, click on ‘IAM & Admin’
4. Click on ‘Add’ at the top of the page.
5. Provide the first service account name from the table above, be sure to replace  with the actual number you obtained in step 1
6. Grant the Admin role for the resource you would like to interact with. Ex. BigQuery Admin for reading/writing to BigQuery. For BigQuery, you will also need to grant the BigQuery Data Owner role as well.
7. Repeat steps 5 & 6 for the second service account in the table above.
8. In your pipeline, ensure you define the correct Project Id for the sources/sinks. Using ‘auto-detect’ will default to the customer project that contains the CDF instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This one actually worked. I suggested this solution to our cloud team and they made changes. I am able to connect to BQ without specifying the service account key file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try download the service key json file to the local, ie you local computer? And try to put the file into some folder and provide the full path to that service key file in the BigQuery properties.

Comment: I tried that but I am getting the below error.

```Unable to load credentials from /Users/accountname/servicekeyfile.json. Ensure the service account file is available on the local filesystem```