# Error in access to BigQuery [Unable to get details about the BigQuery table: Access Denied to BigQuery]

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I've pipeline in project A (pA) which reads from DB2 and try to write in BigQuery of project B (pB), when I try with the validate option into BigQuery sink (before deploy) got this message error:

> Failed to configure pipeline: Stage 'BigQuery' encountered:
> Unable to get details about the BigQuery table:
> Access Denied: Table pA:dataset_1.table_X:
> Permission bigquery.tables.get denied on table pA:dataset_1.table_X (or it may not exist).

Table schema was created on pB (target), and secondly both ***SA of Data Fusion instance*** and ***SA with nomenclature [number-prject-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com]***  in pA contains follows roles:

What other role do I need in the SA of pA?

[Service Accounts of the project A and Roles over Project B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEifw.png)

[Message error on BigQuery properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1f6O.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: From the error message it seems like service account being used does not have access to get bq tables for project P2.

Comment: @vinisha  the SA of instance data fusion of project A has this roles over project B: 
• Cloud Data Fusion API Service Agent
• BigQuery Data Editor
• BigQuery Data Viewer
• BigQuery Job User
• BigQuery Metadata Viewer
• Storage Object Creator
• Storage Object Viewer
The issue here is, what SA I should configure with this roles?, the services account of data fusion instance or SA of compute engine or another?

Comment: So the SA with which Dataproc cluster/job is being created should have permissions.

Comment: Still I've this error, I have not yet deployed, the issue is on the Validate option. I attach an image of the roles of the SA of project A has over BigQuery on project B, I'm using the SA's indicated in the post "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61726314/connect-bigquery-as-a-source-to-data-fusion-in-another-gcp-project ", is there any other service account that I should consider?
  I added new roles to SA1 and SA2, I'm validating the BigQuery Properties and get the above error.

Comment: I solved this issue, data fusion are using two service accounts, the required roles are setting to the instance data fusion SA: cloud-datafusion-management-sa@i798133b6XXXXXXX-tp.iam.gserviceaccount.com and to the second SA for data fusion: service-[project-numbre]@gcp-sa-datafusion.iam.gserviceaccount.com, I don't know why exist two SA's for the same data fusion instance, but work fine.